# Create custom bitmap marker with android map API V2

Tags: android

I'm trying to Create custom bitmap marker and place it at particular Lat-Lng on google Map, for that I have written the following code--

My custom marker view is (user_prof_pic_marker.xml)--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/sz_sixty_five"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sz_sixty_five"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/map_marker" />

<com.wikiNews.custom.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/sz_fifty"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sz_fifty"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/profiledefaultimg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I am setting image to the custom view--

```
View myUserMarkerLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_prof_pic_marker, null);

        myUserImageView = (CircleImageView) myUserMarkerLayout.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        myUserImageView.setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        myUserImageView.setBorderWidth(2);

        //String strPic = UserDetails.getInstance().getCurrentProfilePic();
        if(UserDetails.getInstance().getCurrentProfilePic()!=null && !UserDetails.getInstance().getCurrentProfilePic().isEmpty())
        {
            Picasso.with(this).load(UserDetails.getInstance().getCurrentProfilePic()).into(myUserImageView);
        }
```

My method to create BitMap from custom view is--

```
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

My code to add Marker is--

```
if (googleMap != null)
        {
            final LatLng currentAddressLatLong = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
            //LatLng currentAddressLatLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            Bitmap markerUserBitmap = CommonFunctions.createDrawableFromView(NearByActivity.this, myUserMarkerLayout);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentAddressLatLong).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerUserBitmap)).anchor(0.5f, 1));
}
```

I checked, my code is creating expected bitmap successfully also code to add marker on google map is executing successfully, but marker is not visible on Map. Please guide me and let me know if I can provide more information for the same. Thank you.

Comment: your code seems to be ok.. don't know why marker is not visible to you..!